# Reassign a web domain to a new web server

Tags: domain-name-system, ftp

I have to assign a web domain to point to a new server therefore I need to change the DNS settings, but the webmaster has only given me the FTP hostname/password for the new server path. Is it possible to find the name servers and other required DNS information to reassign the domain to the new server path on my own or I need to ask the webmaster for this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nslookup -type=soa example.com`

The first part is the primary nameserver to make the change the second part in whom to contact and is responsible for the records.